# 200G of Partition was given to ubuntu but all disk analyzer shows only 20G

Tags: partitioning

I read the explanation about the explanation and partition of ubuntu at [DELL][1].
Im new at ubuntu, I started using live CD and I was amazed, then installed it after a week. Out of excitement and eager to use UBUNTU i just watch youtube tutorials to partition it. Succeded in installing and using it for a month and i almost forgot using my Windows10. but after installing my needed software and downloading my files saved in cloud i was greeted that my spce is nearly full. Im sure I gave a 150G partition for UBUNTU.
Here is a screenshot on my [/home (properties)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5sul.png) it shows 148G of available space and 18G of occupied space. But disk analyzer shows this [red warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0are0.png) and this warning [Filesystem root warning][1]..

What should i DO to solve it.
what is Filesystem root really.
where did the 148G go and how will i reclaim and Use it..

edit:
hi thank you for asnwering my question.
here is the sudo fdisk -l screenshot..
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5sul.png) [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0are0.png)  [Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CBZn.png)  [Screenshot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbJ0a.png)  and this is the tutorial [How to Dual Boot Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5QyjHIYwTQ)that I followed during installation. I did what he said... my bad.

edit 2:
here is a picture of [DISKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujl6p.png) (i think)

Comment: Please edit your post with adding the output of `sudo fdisk -l` in Terminal, or a screenshot of Gparted (better, but it isn't installed by default).

Comment: Your root filesystem is probably separate from your '/home' filesystem. Your root file system is running out of space. A `df` and `fdisk` output is needed.

Comment: Off hand till you supply more info as asked, would say you made a /(root) partition and a /home partition, but only listed / as a mount point when installing.  Did you use the 'something else' option when installing?

Comment: Does 'disks' show your home partition as mounted?

Comment: @crip659 what do you mean by disks..? sorry im new on ubuntu... i added a picture of I think the "DISKS" you are pertaining.. Thnx.

Comment: What does disks say your 182GB partition is mounted at?  It should be '/home', if something else is probably where problem is.  You can remove your swap partition and add space to root, need to use the USB installer with 'try Ubuntu" to work on partitions.  Can also move data(videos, docs) to the big partition to free up space.

Comment: Just wondering if your log files has not gone wonky and is filling up space.  Can use disk usage analyzer see what is taking space.

Comment: @crip659. thank you very much for your patience in answering my question.. ill be doing what you said, I am reading now how to add a space for the root and resizing swap partition. like FedonKadifeli said, my root file system is running out. one small step for me... I'm learning now... :)